# C# Unified way to always check whether serial com port is open on multiple buttons

Tags: c#

Normally I would do this to check:

```
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                return;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Please open COM port.", "Status",   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

But I got many buttons in my winform. Around 20 buttons and each button need to check whether the COM port is open before transmitting.

Is it that the only way to do is to add the above coding in every button?

Or there is a one time way?

Comment: Instead of "copy and pasting" code, consider using unified methods ..

Comment: Sorry. Just changed the title.

Comment: Is it only one serial port? (e.g. is `sp` a member variable?) What happens if the sp *is* open? Surely it does something!

Comment: This makes little sense, you open a serial port when you start the program and close it when it terminates.  At no point would you expect the user to have to push a button.  A UI with 20 buttons is a usability problem as well.  Use a toolstrip and/or a menu.

Comment: It is just one serial port. Normally, user have to press the open serial port button first, then only press other buttons for transmitting various data. What if the user forgot to press the open serial port button but straightaway press other buttons for transmit data? I need some warning message.

Comment: Just don't enable those buttons would be my "first" line of defense ..